# PHP - ini_set display_errors off causing error 500

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, http-error

So in my code, I have:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

When I think request the httpCode via CURL, I get back a 500, chrome dev tools says the page has 200.

If I set it to On via that code, I get 200 via CURL.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix/bypass this?

Comment: Your php log and apache/nginx log can help you. Are you using unix? If yes, please do your request by curl then past in your first post the result of the command `tail -n50 /var/log/php*.log`.

Comment: Not sure why that would be, I'd check the logs for any clues as to why. Have you tried with `ini_set("display_errors", 0);` instead? Does the same thing basically.

Comment: @keupsonite No I'm on Windows sorry, where do I find logs on there?

Comment: @Qirel Same results, 500. 1 & On both produce a 200. If I remove the line, I still get a 500.

Comment: @MattCowley No idea, i suggest you to find on Google where your logs can be stocked. Feel free to back to me.